# android app better environment approach

Tags: android, frameworks, development-environment, titanium-mobile

I don't know is this correct question or not here..but me also love titanium framework.

I developed one app that is using classic (not Alloy) titanium frame work.

**+ve points:** the app looks very nice and modifications also very easy on this.

**-ve points:**

1. some times i got unknown crash issues in my app.
2. i am getting load issues at the time of resizing images.
3. my app apk file take around 10MB size.
4. when connect to network some times connection fails at middle of response reading.

**Impotant :** i used my app android only,not in all.
and

***now i wanted to add extra functionality in my app.but due to the above -ve points i wanted to change core android development for developing my app.
is this right decision?***

I need explanation for which is better for app (core android or titanium framework)?

Answer (score 0):

Titanium can be used for applications which are deployed across devices, this is a major advantage; If your requirements are for Android only and you see no reason why you would need to port it to iOS then core Android is the way to go.

The advantage of core Android development

- You have deeper debugging capabilities
- You are not relying on 3rd part APIs
- A lot more users have already encountered the issues you may face, leading to a better range of solutions than a platform with less developers.
- Being native you have the chance to build an app which is not only smaller in size but also better at performing on slower devices.

The disadvantages:

- You may find you struggle with Java (This depends on your programming background)
- An API which is a perfect fit for your specific problem may not be available natively

Comment: I can't solve a problem without you telling me what is wrong. Update your question with more information about your app and maybe I can help.